# How netwrok layers are defined as output in Caffe's net.cpp?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I roughly know that network's outputs are defined in `net.cpp Init`.

`void Net<Dtype>::Init(const NetParameter& in_param)`

Exactly is here at line 240.

```
// In the end, all remaining blobs are considered output blobs.
  for (set<string>::iterator it = available_blobs.begin();
      it != available_blobs.end(); ++it) {
    LOG_IF(INFO, Caffe::root_solver())
        << "This network produces output " << *it;
    net_output_blobs_.push_back(blobs_[blob_name_to_idx[*it]].get());
    net_output_blob_indices_.push_back(blob_name_to_idx[*it]);
  }
```

I have a customized network using Inception Net for faster-rcnn approach.

My network has five convolution layers for RPN.
Then RCNN has two inception layers and one FC layer.

Now the problem is second inception layer is considered in outputs.
Log file shows as

```
I1129 13:21:48.189395 24653 net.cpp:243] This network produces output loss_bbox
I1129 13:21:48.189399 24653 net.cpp:243] This network produces output loss_cls
I1129 13:21:48.189404 24653 net.cpp:243] This network produces output rpn_cls_loss
I1129 13:21:48.189407 24653 net.cpp:243] This network produces output rpn_loss_bbox
I1129 13:21:48.189411 24653 net.cpp:243] This network produces output tower_2/conv
I1129 13:21:48.189415 24653 net.cpp:243] This network produces output tower_2/tower1/conv1_1
I1129 13:21:48.189419 24653 net.cpp:243] This network produces output tower_2/tower2/conv2_2
```

I don't understand why second inception layer is considered as output.

What is wrong with my network architecture?

My whole network can be seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hkzem76klos7ly/train.txt?dl=0).

Comment: I found my problem. The problem is I need a Concat layer after the second inception layer.

Answer (score 0):

Your second inception layer's final output is the ReLU activation:

```
layer {
  name: "tower_2/tower2/conv2_2_relu"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "tower_2/tower2/conv2_2"
  top: "tower_2/tower2/conv2_2"
}
```

Which produces a `top` of `tower_2/tower2/conv2_2`. This top isn't connected to any other layer as a bottom and hence automatically considered as an output.